# Dynamically formatting a string in java

Tags: java

Is there a way to dynamically format a float value?

I thought i could do something like this:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(String.format("%" + k + "s", answer)).toPlainString());
```

Where k is the increments each time through a loop... however, this doesn't seem to do the trick...

i want the numbers to appear like this:

```
0.7897
0.78977
0.789778
0.7897789
```

any ideas?

Comment: is k supposed to be the precision? What kind of format are you tryign to do? Also, why are you creating a BigDecimal based on a String? I'm really confused about what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @crush yes k is the precision

Comment: Hehe. Do you need the actual float value, or just string printing? You could hack it and use `substring`.

Comment: let's say k is 4 and you're input is 0.789, should it print out "0.7890"?

Comment: also, I noticed that you don't seem to round... is this what you want?

Comment: @HansZ i would prefer 0.789 in that case

Comment: @GGrec oh! brilliant! I could do that

Comment: What is `answer`?  If it's a String, what kinds of strings do you expect it could be?  (And the answer is yes, you can use a dynamically created string in `String.format`, but the format does have to be correct.)

Comment: Any place where a `String` is expected you should be able to substitute a dynamically created `String` for a literal value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (int i=3; i<10; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%1." + i + "f", Math.PI));
}
```

Something like that should work

```
[tmp] % java Foo
3.142
3.1416
3.14159
3.141593
3.1415927
3.14159265
3.141592654
```

Comment: this would work but the example in the question doesn't round.

Comment: Wanted to mention `"%."+i+"f"` but I thought I was thinking in C++. Very good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using a [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) can be done like this example

```
 float f = 0.342566246
 NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getInstance()
 for(int i = 2; i< 6;i++)
 {
     n.setMaximumFractionDigits(i)
     System.out.println(n.format(f))
 }
```

Gives, which rounds.

```
0.34
0.343
0.3426
0.34257
```

You can control rounding by adding a [RoundingMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)  eg adding

```
n.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Gives

```
0.34
0.342
0.3425
0.34256
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

I can't help you any further since I don't know the format you're interested in.

Comment: Hey, @CommuSoft, you should try to summarize the contents of your link instead of having just a link in answers in case of linkrot. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the actual float value of your variables, you can just print them out in the loop using the `subString` API from `String`.

The advantage is that your formatted variable won't be rounded. This is a hack-ish alternative to the other two answers.